# React heroicons icons are always black

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, tailwind-css, heroicons

I'm using `@heroicons/react: ^1.0.5` and I'm trying to style the icons by applying another color. I'm using `tailwindcss` to manage my CSS.

When I declare the following component inside a `button` tag

```
<PencilIcon className='text-white' />
```

I get the following result on my browser (Chrome 95)

[image: Purple button on a white background with white text, the button has a black trailing pencil icon]

The exact same code works when I access the app on my phone with Chrome 95 (the pencil icon is white).

This is the generated HTML for the icon:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" class="text-white">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15.232 5.232l3.536 3.536m-2.036-5.036a2.5 2.5 0 113.536 3.536L6.5 21.036H3v-3.572L16.732 3.732z"></path>
</svg>
```

When I open the devtools I can see that the computed color of the `svg` tag is indeed `white` but the computed color for the `path` tag is `rgb(17, 24, 39)` which is inherited from the following CSS rule I have in my global CSS file.

```css
*
{
    font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
    @apply text-gray-900;
}
```

Commenting the `@apply` directive solves my issue but I'm curious as to why it's behaving in this way. Especially when the Chrome on my phone can handle it okay.

Comment: Try the property `fill="white"`

Answer (score 1):

You can add color with color prop:

`<PencilIcon color='#FFFFFF' />`

It is not the best practice to use global style in scss file.

I am surprised that you was able to do it. I am getting an error:

```
Syntax error: Selector "*" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)
```